# In the data frame of probabilities over time return first column name where value is < .5 for each row

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas data frame like the following where the column names are the time, the rows are each of the subjects, and the values are probabilities return the column name (or time) the first time the probability is less than .50 for each subject in the data frame. The probabilities are always descending from 1-0 I. have tried looping though the data frame but it is not computationally efficient.

| subject id | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | … | 669 | 670 | 671 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.997913 | 0.993116 | 0.989017 | 0.976157 | 0.973078 | 0.968056 | 0.963685 | … | 0.156092 | 0.156092 | 0.156092 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.990335 | 0.988685 | 0.983145 | 0.964912 | 0.958 | 0.952 | 0.946995 | … | 0.148434 | 0.148434 | 0.148434 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.996231 | 0.990571 | 0.985775 | 0.976809 | 0.972736 | 0.969633 | 0.966116 | … | 0.17037 | 0.17037 | 0.17037 |
| 4 | 1 | 0.997129 | 0.994417 | 0.991054 | 0.978795 | 0.974216 | 0.96806 | 0.963039 | … | 0.15192 | 0.15192 | 0.15192 |
| 5 | 1 | 0.997728 | 0.993598 | 0.986641 | 0.98246 | 0.977371 | 0.972874 | 0.96816 | … | 0.154545 | 0.154545 | 0.154545 |
| 6 | 1 | 0.998134 | 0.995564 | 0.989901 | 0.986941 | 0.982313 | 0.972951 | 0.969645 | … | 0.17473 | 0.17473 | 0.17473 |
| 7 | 1 | 0.995681 | 0.994131 | 0.990401 | 0.974494 | 0.967941 | 0.961859 | 0.956636 | … | 0.144753 | 0.144753 | 0.144753 |
| 8 | 1 | 0.997541 | 0.994904 | 0.991941 | 0.983389 | 0.979375 | 0.973158 | 0.966358 | … | 0.158763 | 0.158763 | 0.158763 |
| 9 | 1 | 0.992253 | 0.989064 | 0.979258 | 0.955747 | 0.948842 | 0.942899 | 0.935784 | … | 0.150291 | 0.150291 | 0.150291 |

Goal Output

| subject id | time prob < .05 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 99 |
| 3 | 34 |
| 4 | 19 |
| 5 | 600 |
| 6 | 500 |
| 7 | 222 |
| 8 | 111 |
| 9 | 332 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the probabilities are always descending you can do this:

```
>>> df.set_index("subject id").gt(.98).sum(1)
subject id
1    4
2    4
3    4
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    4
8    5
9    3
dtype: int64
```

note: I'm using `.98` instead of `.5` because I'm using only a portion of the data.

---

Data used

```
{'subject id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9},
 '0': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 '1': {0: 0.997913,
  1: 0.990335,
  2: 0.996231,
  3: 0.997129,
  4: 0.997728,
  5: 0.998134,
  6: 0.995681,
  7: 0.997541,
  8: 0.992253},
 '2': {0: 0.993116,
  1: 0.988685,
  2: 0.990571,
  3: 0.994417,
  4: 0.993598,
  5: 0.995564,
  6: 0.994131,
  7: 0.994904,
  8: 0.989064},
 '3': {0: 0.989017,
  1: 0.983145,
  2: 0.985775,
  3: 0.991054,
  4: 0.986641,
  5: 0.989901,
  6: 0.990401,
  7: 0.991941,
  8: 0.979258},
 '4': {0: 0.976157,
  1: 0.964912,
  2: 0.976809,
  3: 0.978795,
  4: 0.98246,
  5: 0.986941,
  6: 0.974494,
  7: 0.983389,
  8: 0.955747},
 '5': {0: 0.973078,
  1: 0.958,
  2: 0.972736,
  3: 0.974216,
  4: 0.977371,
  5: 0.982313,
  6: 0.967941,
  7: 0.979375,
  8: 0.948842},
 '6': {0: 0.968056,
  1: 0.952,
  2: 0.969633,
  3: 0.96806,
  4: 0.972874,
  5: 0.972951,
  6: 0.961859,
  7: 0.973158,
  8: 0.942899},
 '7': {0: 0.963685,
  1: 0.946995,
  2: 0.966116,
  3: 0.963039,
  4: 0.96816,
  5: 0.969645,
  6: 0.956636,
  7: 0.966358,
  8: 0.935784}}
```

Comment: @user14473305 I'm happy to help! :D

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
df.where(df.lt(.5)).idxmax(axis=1)
```